# C++ create vector of a struct inside a class

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector, struct

I think I might have an oddly specific/weird question that I might be making more complex then it needs to be.

I have a simple class:

```
class Foo{

public:
    struct Bar{
        int otherdata;
    };
    int somedata;
};
```

In another file I import this class and create an Instance of Foo

I also want to create a vector of type Bar..how would I do this?

I have tried:

```
//Assume I already imported proper prereqs
int main() {
    Foo test;
    vector<test::Bar> vec;
    //or
    vector<test.Bar> vec;
    //or
    vector<Bar> vec;
}
```

Whats the best way to do this? I can simply do this if I take the struct and place it outside the class..but is there a way to encapsulate the struct and create a vector of that type of struct. I should point out that I do not want to initialize the vector inside the class, but rather in my main function.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
 vector<Foo::Bar> vec;
```

Comment: smh...interesting how simply test::bar won't work and you have to just directly call the class without creating an instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `vector<Foo::Bar>`.

The structure/class `Bar` will always have one int regardless of the instance of `Foo`, so it makes no sense (or at least it's redundant) to qualify it with `test` as in `test::Bar` or `test.Bar`. Hence, we qualify it as `Foo::Bar`.